# Need to check limit of these sequences!

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

For the first one I got the limit to be infinity and for the second one I got it to be 1/8

Comment: All correct.  Strange it's always "none of the above"

Answer (score 1):

For the first one you can see that: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{3^{3n+3}+n^39^{9/n}}{9^n+n^93^{3/n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{3^{3(n+1)}+n^39^{9/n}}{9^n+n^93^{3/n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\color{blue}{27^{n+1}}+n^39^{9/n}}{9^n+n^93^{3/n}}$$
and that $\color{blue}{\text{term}}$ blows up very quickly relative to the other terms, which makes the hole thing diverging. And so the answer to that limit is simply $\infty$.

For the second limit you got the right answer.